# How to call C++ DLL from C# when one of the parameters is an array of pointers

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a DLL pin C++ which takes two parameters, similar to main() function in C: Number of  argurments, followed by an array of pointers to individual parameters:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void Calculate(int argc, void** argv)
{
    if (argc >= 7)
    {
        auto sourceX = *((int*)(argv[0]));
        auto sourceY = *((int*)(argv[1]));
        auto iterations = *((int*)(argv[2]));
        auto resize = *((bool*)(argv[3]));
        auto input = (double*)(argv[4]);
        auto targetX = *((int*)(argv[5]));
        auto targetY = *((int*)(argv[6]));

        // Do computations
    }
}
```

I am able to call the exported function from another C code (after loading the DLL library via a LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress calls) in this manner:

```
int X, Y, iterations;
bool Resize;
double* Input;

// Initialize variables, allocate data for Input
// ...

void* Params[] = { &X, &Y,  &iterations, &Resize, Input, &X, &Y };

_Calculate(7, Params);
```

However, when I tried calling the DLL from C#, it crashes. Here is the C# snippet that I'm using:

```
[DllImport("computedll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void Calculate(int argc, void** argv);

public void Compute()
{
    int X, Y, iterations;
    bool Resize;
    double* Input;

    // Initialize variables, allocate data for Input
    // ...

    var Parameters = stackalloc void*[7];

    Parameters[0] = &X;
    Parameters[1] = &Y;
    Parameters[2] = &iterations;
    Parameters[3] = &Resize;
    Parameters[4] = Input;
    Parameters[5] = &X; 
    Parameters[6] = &Y;

    Calculate(7, Parameters);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there no way to make this pattern of using array of pointers (void**) work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pinvoke/info

Comment: Guessing you've already verified your C++ code and your C# code are using the same pointer sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built as x64, the following works.  It's very nearly your code.  I hate using cdecl outside C/C++, so if that's important to you....sorry.  Point is...if you are having problems, it's not fundamental to your actual code or concept.

Interopy.h:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Calculate(int argc, void** argv);
}
```

Source:

```
#include "Interopy.h"
void __stdcall Calculate(int argc, void** argv)
{
  if (argc >= 7)
  {
    auto sourceX = *((int*)(argv[0]));
    auto sourceY = *((int*)(argv[1]));
    auto iterations = *((int*)(argv[2]));
    auto resize = *((bool*)(argv[3]));
    auto input = (double*)(argv[4]);
    auto targetX = *((int*)(argv[5]));
    auto targetY = *((int*)(argv[6]));
    *(int*)argv[5] = 42; //to test

    // Do computations
  }
}
```

c# (Platform target x64):

```
  public static class iop
  {

  [DllImport("InteropyDll1.dll",  CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    unsafe public static extern void Calculate(int argc, void** argv);

    unsafe static public void Compute()
    {
        int X, Y, iterations;
        bool Resize;
        double* Input = (double*)IntPtr.Zero;

        // Initialize variables, allocate data for Input
        // ...

        void **Parameters = stackalloc void*[7];

        Parameters[0] = &X;
        Parameters[1] = &Y;
        Parameters[2] = &iterations;
        Parameters[3] = &Resize;
        Parameters[4] = Input;
        Parameters[5] = &X;
        Parameters[6] = &Y;

        Calculate(7, Parameters);
    }
  }
```

Note that this assembly is now platform dependent.  I've solved this in the past with multiple build configurations, but I'm sure there are better ways to go.  In any event, you'll want to put this unsafe code in its own assembly for that and other reasons.

Comment: Thanks you for this! I implemented your suggestions and it worked out very well! I tried up-voting your answer, unfortunately my reputation (6) isn't enough.

Comment: @StephenDaedalusSepara You can always accept it being the asker though. A checkmark next to it, I believe?

Comment: @StephenDaedalusSepara - btw, I don't know the purpose of this code, but if it's something you'll be maintaining, I'd keep an eye on `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` in C# 7.2.  They are designed for scenarios like these to not need unsafe.  Pretty beta at the moment, though.

Comment: The (legacy) c++ codes are used to perform computations that are otherwise not available or slower in c# now. Yes, I would be maintaining those codes for a while until we get better implementations of the computations. It looks like `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` are going to be interesting and useful developments to c#, many thanks again for this.